# Should new users be pinged if they abandon their question?

Tags: discussion, new-users

We have all seen it before: a new user comes to the site, asks a valid/well-formed question, gets some valid/well-formed answers, and then proceeds to abandon their question without interacting with the answers.

The fact that their question has answers that could **potentially** help others is a great asset to the site, but at the same time, this new user missed a key opportunity to get familiar with how the site functions. Not only that, another *"unanswered"* question gets lost in a sea of unanswered questions, even though it has answers that could have been selected if the OP didn't abandon it.

To this I ask, should SO ping new users who abandon their question? Most likely if the following conditions are met:

- The question is still open.
- The question received answers.
- At least one of the answers has >= 0 votes.
- The OP did not accept any of the answers.
- The OP did not comment/interact with the answers.
- If the OP did vote on an answer, they did not comment on it or accept it.
- A fixed amount of time has passed (a week, a month?)

This ping could be in the form of a notification to their SO inbox or even maybe an email. It would just alert the user that they recently asked a question that was answered, but they have not yet interacted with the answers.

To go one step further, should a user be reprimanded if they repeatedly abandon questions?

Comment: _"The OP did not comment/interact with the answers"_ The reminder could be even more entailed _sometimes_ if the OP leaves a comment (e.g., "Thank you" comments).

Comment: I believe if that "reminder" feature is ever considered, the best place to use it would be when the user goes to ask a new question.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That is true, there is also an issue with OPs not accepting answers despite interacting with them like saying "Thank you". At least in these cases, the OP may not have completely abandoned it, and a comment can point them to the Accept Answer functionality.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That is a good idea. It would be a lot harder for the user to ignore the notification if it pops up when asking a new question as opposed to just going to their inbox.

Comment: What make you think they abandon the qestion? Maybe they just take a break

Comment: @TGrif I guess that would be where the time constraint comes in. I am not sure what the best period would be, but I think it would be a safe assumption if the OP has not interacted with the question in about a month, they most likely abandoned it. Even if they did not abandon it and are just taking a break, what does it hurt to give them a reminder?

Comment: Some of these "abandoned" questions are from users that come to the site, ask their question, get an answer, and never come back.  Pinging anything onsite would not be seen by these users, so you'd have to go with an email ping.  Would the time since the user last logged in be a factor in when/if to ping?

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250797/476201)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm While that is true to a degree, I would be hard pressed to believe that anyone in a software development role (student, job, etc.) would ask a question and then never come back to the site. For most people in any of those roles, they know how indispensable SO is for for their learning and development. However, there will still be one-off cases of people who have SO-related questions, but are not developers by trade/hobby and may never come back to the site.

Comment: You are missing something - the user did not **Vote** on any of the answers.  Some people don't accept answers for their own reasons.  And they might not need to comment.  But if the user voted (up or down), then they definately addressed the answer in some form

Comment: @psubsee2003 I meant to use the term "interact" in the "The OP did not comment/interact with the answers" bullet to be a catch all for voting/accepting/etc. Sorry for not being clear, will fix. Also, if the OP has answers that they have not interacted with and they have also not accepted an answer, it seems reasonable for them to at least comment on the answers they got to let them know why it did/did not answer their question.

Comment: I sometimes send a ping myself when I have the gut feeling the OP solved the problem themselves meanwhile. Usually in the form of "Did you resolve the problem? If so, feel free to share the solution in an answer to give this question proper closure" or a variation thereof. It has worked out well a few times, not so well some other times because the produced answer was not very valuable. I don't find it a good idea to automate this.

Answer (score 9):

/shrug

I'm not really seeing the value.

Ultimately, if a user asks a good question and gets *great* answers, then those great answers will be reachable to others through search engines, and the community would be willing to upvote them.

If the OP never came back to interact with those answers, or learn more about how the site works, I suppose that's their loss, but for their narrow use case, they got the value they wanted - someone came and answered their question.

Comment: That is true, but there is still the questions that do not receive as much attention. Maybe they are working with a niche technology, and their question is valid but not overwhelmingly popular. The questions/answers might not receive any votes, but that doesn't mean the question/answer couldn't help other users in the future.

Comment: If that's the case, then why punish the OP twice?  Once because they asked a question in a niche technology which doesn't get any traction, and twice because they've now been notified that they're not "interacting enough with their question"?  I don't see what notifying the OP about their question would actually accomplish there.

Comment: They would only be notified if they have not interacted with the answers they received. If the question received no answers or it received answers that the OP interacted with, there would be no notification. I do not see that as being punished. They would only be "punished" if they repeatedly abandon questions based on the criteria outlined in the question. That does not seam unreasonable to me, but I am still new to contributing to the SO community so take my opinions with a grain of salt.

Comment: I mean, I'm still not seeing the *value* in this.  This doesn't take into account the very, very legitimate use case of people who ask questions and don't otherwise engage with the actual site.

Comment: Unfortunately, to a degree, I do agree. I doubt that notifications would do much to stop people from abandoning questions. If there was a way to do it effectively, I think it would bring some value. I frequently find myself checking recent answers I gave to see the OP abandoned the question before interacting with the answers, so I comment to see if the OP needs any more help and it is *usually* ineffective.

Comment: I didn't know about that use case. Thank you for making me aware of it, but is that a use case that SO should encourage? Should asking questions that are then abandoned by the OP be an acceptable use case for SO?

Comment: "Should encourage" is probably not the phrase I'd use.  At least I wouldn't want to see it inhibited because, well, that's fundamentally impossible.  You'd be putting up a windscreen in front of a train, figuratively speaking.  Millions of users do this ***all the time***, and from Stack Overflow's perspective, the value is in the good answers that those questions brought.  It really doesn't matter if the OP is gone and can't interact.  There are *some* OP's who can't interact, either because they're deceased or arrested, so this would do them no favors.

Comment: @JamesMchugh I had an answer that got accepted this week. My answer is about two years old. Sometimes they come back and start learning how it works and start accepting old answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, if an abandoned question gets answers (some of which could've been accepted as the correct answer) but none of them get accepted,  potentially duplicate questions couldn't be duplicated to it as it has no accepted answers.  Of course, one could just link the new question to this abandoned question and hope the poster figures it out themselves.

Comment: @ewokx you can vote to close as duplicate even when the target has an answer with score greater than 1. So technically you can cast a close vote by upvoting an answer.

Answer (score 7):

I would change your criteria slightly:

- The question is still open
- The question received answers.
- At least one of the answers has >= 0 votes
- The OP did not *accept* any of the answers
- The OP did not comment on either an answer or reply to a comment on the question itself
- A fixed amount of time has passed (maybe a month)

Though, I think something like this might already exist.

> This ping could be in the form of a notification to their SO inbox or even maybe an email.

Notification in SO inbox definitely. I already get a bunch of emails like this from platforms (Twitter, Facebook) that I ignore. I really don't like the idea of SO/SE sending an email. I think most people would probably just ignore it anyway.

> It would just alert the user that they recently asked a question that was answered, but they have not yet interacted with the answers.

I feel like something like this already exists on the network already, but again I could be wrong.

> To go one step further, should a user be reprimanded if they repeatedly abandon questions?

If they ask good questions that generate good answers, those answers  are still useful to the site and future readers regardless if the OP comments on them. Sure, it'd be nice to have an accepted answer, but it's not necessary.

On the other hand, if they are decreasing the quality of the site, then they should probably be reprimanded. But we already have mechanisms in place for this already.

So, I don't see the point of adding a special reason to reprimand someone.

Comment: Good point. I meant to add that the OP did not accept the answer in the question, so I just added that now. I do agree that an email notification would probably be ignore. A inbox notification or even what @AhmedAbdelhameed suggested in the question comments, notifying the user when they ask a new question, would be preferred.

Comment: Also, while it is great that the user is asking good questions that is receiving good answers, should there be no warning to the user if they are repeatedly abandoning questions? This would suggest to me that they are not using the site as it was intended. I personally cannot imagine asking a question, having users take the time to answer it, and then not even accepting/commenting/voting on their answers.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, no. One thing I really like about this site is that people have the freedom to vote or abstain from voting on anything however they want to (as long as they aren't being abusive) without any* restrictions or repercussions.

I think people should be free to not accept an answer without being bothered about it.

<sub>*I know you have to reach certain thresholds to up/down vote and that you lose points for downvoting answers</sub>

Comment: I can understand not voting on an answer that you do not necessarily agree/disagree with. However, if you post a question and get answers, shouldn't there be some reasonable expectation for the OP to have some sort of interaction with those answers through commenting, accepting, or voting?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by expectation. I think acknowledging the answers in some way is a polite thing to do (at least it is in my culture) but I don't think people should be pressured to do it.