# Is there a penalty for users who repeatedly abandon their questions?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, a question might not be answered correctly, and the original poster might want to clarify and/or give feedback — and that's expected.

But what about users who abandon questions without providing any feedback or engagement?

Additionally, I have noticed numerous instances where the original poster comments, "this worked!" but fails to mark the answer as accepted. However, I believe this issue should be addressed on a case-by-case basis. Nevertheless, forming a habit of abandoning questions is not acceptable.

PS: I believe this situation differs slightly from the discussion on whether [new users should be pinged if they abandon their question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391680/should-new-users-be-pinged-if-they-abandon-their-question) because it involves not just one question but a pattern of abandoning questions.

Comment: Hey Gert, sadly no. My concern is about "serial abandoners" - users who consistently abandon multiple questions over time.

Comment: If their questions are bad (i.e. they get downvoted / closed) they will eventually get question banned, there is no penalty for abandoning questions though. If the questions were well received (i.e. upvoted) then there is no reason for any penalty.

Comment: But when is someone a _serial_ abandoner? At any rate, it's all in the same sphere of slight annoyances. In the end, without being sentimental, we, answerers, shouldn't answer questions only for the points. It's fun to get them, let's face it, but helping people without reward makes anyone a better person, is my belief.

Comment: If the question asker never updated the question with information requested, it will remain closed. This will count towards the question ban.

Comment: Marking an answer as accepted is completely optional and we never pressure anyone to mark any answer as accepted. It's the prerogative of question asker if they wish to put their mark of approval on a single answer.

Comment: Hopefully, when you ask a user to add information to their question, and they don't, it means that finding that information and thinking about it allowed them to solve the problem themselves. Maybe self answering should be promoted more?

Comment: The Question you link to yourself ("[Should new users be pinged if they abandon their question?](/q/391680/3799241)") is actually a very close Duplicate as it's not only that "*it involves (not) just one question*", but it also contains: "*[To go one step further,] should a user be reprimanded if they repeatedly abandon questions?*" which is exactly your Title/Question.

Comment: I do believe that... let's call them enthusiastic people post their questions on several sites at the same time and will just respond to the ones that are the nicest about it. That'll hardly ever be Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow is mean with all its demands of quality and clarity.

Comment: If the OP is being unresponsive to requests for clarification, feel free to downvote and flag to close (after the strike is over, of course).

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's one question, a dozen questions, a hundred questions, or however many questions the OP chooses to not engage with further.  The end sentiment is still the same - they're free to engage with the site however much or however little they want to.  This isn't Reddit where engagement is king, nor is it Twitter where engagement has to happen in near-real time.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users

Comment: "My concern is about "serial abandoners" - users who consistently abandon multiple questions over time." - and *why* does this concern you?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel a strong sense of belonging to something greater than oneself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We don't penalize people for simply walking away from the screen at any time.

We do have positive reinforcement. There are green Internet points to be had for marking an answer "the answer".

For those answering, the actual OP of the question is not really the main source of green Internet points. I mean yes, it is, but there is a maximum of 25 to be had, while all the other people reading the question and finding the answer helpful will do much more to that green score.

So to summarize: everybody is free to leave at any time without being penalized. Staying on is rewarded though.